# SQL String format for Full Text Search in C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a parameterized sql string which I want to end up as this when executed on the database server, which when executed, returns the desired results:

```
SELECT * FROM OrderHeader WHERE FacilityId = 9 AND CONTAINS(*,'"Rich*"')
```

I've tried the three attempts below and the result, but can't get it to come out like above goal statement and the result is either a `syntax error near '@p1'` in the first statement, and zero results in the second two statements.

Attempt 1:

```
string sql = "SELECT * " +
    "FROM OrderHeader " +
    "WHERE FacilityId = @p0 AND CONTAINS(*,\"@p1*\")";

var orderByCustomerFullTextQuery = base.DbSet.SqlQuery(sql, intFacilityId, strSearchTerm).AsQueryable();

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM OrderHeader WHERE FacilityId = @p0 AND CONTAINS(*,"@p1*")',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4)',@p0=9,@p1=N'Rich'
```

Attempt 2:

```
string sql = "SELECT * " +
    "FROM OrderHeader " +
    "WHERE FacilityId = @p0 AND CONTAINS(*,'\"@p1*\"')";

var orderByCustomerFullTextQuery = base.DbSet.SqlQuery(sql, intFacilityId, strSearchTerm).AsQueryable();

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM OrderHeader WHERE FacilityId = @p0 AND CONTAINS(*,''"@p1*"'')',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4)',@p0=9,@p1=N'Rich'
```

Attempt 3:

```
string sql = "SELECT * " +
    "FROM OrderHeader " +
    "WHERE FacilityId = @p0 AND CONTAINS(*,\'\"@p1*\"\')";

var orderByCustomerFullTextQuery = base.DbSet.SqlQuery(sql, intFacilityId, strSearchTerm).AsQueryable();

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM OrderHeader WHERE FacilityId = @p0 AND CONTAINS(*,''"@p1*"'')',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4)',@p0=9,@p1=N'Rich'
```

Comment: I think you need to remove * at all from your query and append this * to your parameter, plz let me know if it works to post as an answer

Comment: @msoliman so am I to assume that you were the one that down voted my question as you deleted your answer? If so, not cool. Joel got me to a working solution first, hence his answer got accepted. Though I think you were on the right track, you were just a bit too late.

Comment: I just deleted my answer as the other answer was verified by you as correct and worked fine with you so why should I keep mine too, that is it

Comment: @msoliman understood, just wondering why someone down voted but didn't explain why. I'm always looking to improve my questions here on SO, so if there is an issue with it, I'd hope that if someone feels enough to down vote it, that they'd share their reason why so I can improve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string sql = "SELECT * " +
    "FROM OrderHeader " +
    "WHERE FacilityId = @p0 AND CONTAINS(*,'\"' + @p1 + '*\"')";
```

The problem with the other attempts is the `@p1` variable was evaluated in the `sp_executesql` context as part of a larger `"@p1*"` string literal. It wasn't an element in the query... just part of a string literal. We can separate the `@p1` variable from the full `"@p1*"`  value by breaking this up into three separate pieces: a literal for the leading quote, just the `@p1`, and a literal for the trailing wildcard and quote. It should give you the equivalent of executing this query:

```
SELECT * FROM OrderHeader WHERE FacilityId = 9 AND CONTAINS(*,'"' + 'Rich' + '*"')
```

Failing this (though it really should work), you can also try tweaking the values as you assign them to the parameter:

```
string sql = "SELECT * " +
    "FROM OrderHeader " +
    "WHERE FacilityId = @p0 AND CONTAINS(*, @p1)";

...SqlQuery(sql, intFacilityId, "\"" + strSearchTerm + "*\"").AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Hmmm, that is throwing an `incorrect syntax near '+'` error

Comment: your last edit ended up with the same answer I gave however @chad mentioned it did not work with him

Comment: Your second version worked! It rendered `exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM OrderHeader WHERE FacilityId = @p0 AND CONTAINS(*, @p1)',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(7)',@p0=9,@p1=N'"Rich*"'`. Thank you!