# This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities error with full text search

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, projection, iqueryable

Having a problem when trying to use full text search and projecting to a view model because of the `DbFunctions.AddHours` function call. If no value was entered into the Search view model to trigger the full text search method, then all works fine. But as soon as you trigger the full text search method, then call the view model projection, I get the error:

> This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.

In both cases, the code is passing an `IQueryable<OrderHeader>` to the view model projection, so i'm not sure why the full text search method doesn't work or if there is a way to make it work.

In the code you will see I enumerate the `IQueryable` first to a list, then mark that `AsQueryable`, as an attempted work around, which also didn't work. But 
 I originally passed just the `Orders` `IQueryable` and both give the same error.

I'd like to not have to write two different view model projection methods to use depending on if the full text search is triggered or not, is it possible?

**BONUS QUESTION:** Ideally, I'd also like to combine the full text IQueryable result with following criteria...so continue to be able to chain additional `.Where` clauses onto that full text search IQueryable result (eg. like the last line of `IsStorePickup` clause)...is that possible?

Query Logic:

```
IQueryable<OrderHeader> Orders = _orderHeaderRepository
    .SearchFor(x => 
        x.FacilityId == intFacilityId
        && x.OrderType == strOrderType);

//Get Filters
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchViewModel.CustomerFreeText))
{
    Orders = _orderHeaderRepository.GetOrdersByCustomerFullTextSearch(intFacilityId, searchViewModel.CustomerFreeText);

    return listViewModel.ConvertClassToViewModel(Orders.ToList().AsQueryable());
}

if (searchViewModel.IsStorePickup) 
{ 
    Orders = _orderHeaderRepository.SearchFor(Orders, x => x.PickUpInStore == true); 
}
```

Full Text Search method, which returns an `IQueryable<OrderHeader>`

```
public IQueryable<OrderHeader> GetOrdersByCustomerFullTextSearch(int intFacilityId, string strSearchTerm)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * " +
        "FROM OrderHeader " +
        "WHERE FacilityId = @p0 AND CONTAINS(*, @p1)";

    var orderByCustomerFullTextQuery = base.DbSet.SqlQuery(sql, intFacilityId, "\"" + strSearchTerm + "*\"").AsQueryable();

    return orderByCustomerFullTextQuery;
}
```

View Model projection:

```
IQueryable<ShipOrderSearchResultsViewModel> viewModel =
    orders.Select(oh => new ShipOrderSearchResultsViewModel()
        {
            ...
           CreatedOn = System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddHours(oh.CreatedOn, userTimeZoneOffset).Value
            ...
        });
```

Comment: try changing base.DbSet.SqlQuery to   _orderHeaderRepository.OrderHeaders.SqlQuery or _orderHeaderRepository.Database.SqlQuery<OrderHeader>    depending on what type _orderHeaderRepository is

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath in my case it would be `_orderHeaderRepository.dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<OrderHeader>(sql,...)`....but no luck, still the same error.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with "\"" + strSearchTerm + "*\"".  What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: use LinqKit, and you can locate some equivalent AddHours functions for Linq for EF, https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448322/how-to-add-hours-to-date-using-linq-query

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath no, that part works fine. That is to use a contains type full text search. We got that working via my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917300/sql-string-format-for-full-text-search-in-c-sharp-entity-framework?noredirect=1#comment82803208_47917300. Its the dbfunction.addhours part that is the issue. But thank you for the consideration.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that as you are running raw SQL there is no connection between what is returned by `base.DbSet.SqlQuery` call. So when you try to run `DbFunctions.AddHours`, it fails because this will need to run on SQL Server! As the results have already materialized in the form of `OrderHeader` objects, there is no trip to DB. So try using simple `DateTime.Add`.